# NODE APP: Systemd startup script not working?

Tags: node.js, systemd, upstart, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to create a start up script for my nodejs app which runs on port 3000.

> **Issue**: The node-app.server script is not working and I think it's because `ExecStart` pathway is wrong. *When I go to the server IP in Chrome nothing shows.*

The node app was created with npm generator, and I normally use `npm start` to start the app. I've added path to bin/wwww, here:

```
[Unit]
Description=tweetMonster twtiter server - making your environment variables rad
Documentation=https://example.com
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=NODE_PORT=3000
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/twitter-server/bin/www.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My app is running on Ubuntu 18 at `/home/ubuntu/twitter-server` . And if do `ls`:

```
/twitter-server$ ls
app.js  node_modules       package.json  routes
bin     package-lock.json  public        views
```

Please help!

**ERROR TERMINAL:**

```
Nov 01 05:40:25 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: node-app.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Nov 01 05:40:25 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: node-app.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 01 05:40:26 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: node-app.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 01 05:40:26 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: node-app.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 01 05:40:26 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: Stopped hello_env.js - making your environment variables rad.
Nov 01 05:40:26 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: node-app.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 01 05:40:26 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: node-app.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 01 05:40:26 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: Failed to start hello_env.js - making your environment variables rad.
Nov 01 06:20:11 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/node-app.service:10: Executable path is not absolute: "node /home/ubuntu/twitter-server/bin/www.js"
Nov 01 06:24:35 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/node-app.service:10: Executable path is not absolute: "node /home/ubuntu/twitter-server/bin/www.js"
root@ip-172-31-22-207:/etc/systemd/system#
```

Comment: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/twitter-server/bin/www.js': No such file or directory... Okay im on an EC2 instance logged in as root. The node app directory is under ubuntu user.

Comment: do `su ubuntu` then try: `ls /home/ubuntu/twitter-server/bin/www.js`

Comment: also try `/home/ubuntu/twitter-server/bin/`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to be logged in as root user in order to add script in systemd

Comment: Also, why does your ExecStart script say `twitter-server`, and your question also  mention `analysis-server`

Comment: That worked! ls /home/ubuntu/twitter-server/bin/ shows www in terminal

Comment: That's a typo, im in twitter-server, will fix

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your service config.

First, wrap the value of `Environment` with double quotes:

```
Environment="NODE_PORT=3000"
```

Second,

You need to use  `node` to run the `ExecStart` script. `/home/ubuntu/twitter-server/bin/www.js` is no command in itself.

Do,

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '$$(which node) /home/ubuntu/twitter-server/bin/www.js'
```

Comment: Okay, made the changes. How do I run it. I'm trying to do: sudo systemctl status node-app  and then sudo systemtl enable node-app  but initial error:

Comment: Nov 01 05:40:26 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: Failed to start hello_env.js - making your environment variables rad.
Nov 01 06:20:11 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/node-app.service:10: Executable path is not absolute: "node /home/ubuntu/twitter-server/bin/www.js"
root@ip-172-31-22-207:/etc/systemd/system#

Comment: Same issue: Weirdly the error in terminal has the description: "hello_env.js - making your environment variables rad."
but my updated description is: Description= twtiter server - making your environment variables rad

Comment: Is the script not updating perhaps when I run sudo systemctl status node-app

Comment: do `sudo  systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: I don't understand where this is from: Nov 01 05:40:26 ip-172-31-22-207 systemd[1]: Stopped hello_env.js - making your environment variables rad.  I have noo hello_env.js (this was a tutorial file name)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend this package ([service-systemd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/service-systemd)) for a simple program

Sometimes you just want an "old style" daemon for simple services.
Sometimes you have to deploy in small devices (like a RaspberryPi) and you can't use Docker and all the band.